# Send data from JSP to Java program

Tags: java, jsp

I'm a beginner to JSP (started today) and wanted to send some data (which I have got in a JSP file from an HTML form) to a JAVA program where I could use it.

Peterclass is the name of the Java program I'm gonna be making/using.

Suppose my JSP file is like this:

```
<%@ page import="com.example.Peterclass"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<html>
    <body>
        <%
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
        %>
        <h1>
            Hello, <%=username%>!
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I wanted to receive the values of username and password variables in a JAVA program (I'm using Tomcat server for the purpose). How shall I do it? Please be as simple as you can be.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend a tutorial and servlet overviews before going too much further-since this is an answer easy to search for and find, it might not be the best fit.  Also check out the SO tag docs for JSP and servlets for ready-made offsite links.

Comment: Look into Spring MVC. Here is a good tutorial to learn from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm Then you can look into [Form Handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm)

Comment: I know that would be right but since this was something that needs to be done in a very short period of time. I have tried few approaches but I get resolving or compiling errors.
Thanks.

Comment: Spring MVC can be up and running in a day, pretty easily.

Comment: I agree that there are many tutorials that can walk you through this. In short, you need a form tag that surrounds your form. This tag will tell the browser where to post the data to (default url is the url where the html came from). You need to either handle the post request with another jsp or a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need a so called "Servlet" to work with request and response Parameter.
Here is a first tutorial on how to create and use servlets:
[Click here](http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/A%20servlet%20example.aspx)

Another tip for you:
It is not state of the art to use so called Scriptlets.
Scriptlets is a form of Java-Code in JSP Sites:

```
<%
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
%>
```

You can easily get the parameter you set in your Servlet with:

```
${requestScope.<<PARAMETERNAME>>}
e.g. ${requestScope.username}
```

or if your parameter is in the HTTPSession:

```
${sessionScope.<<PARAMETERNAME>>}
```

your jsp side would look like this afterwards:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>
        Hello, ${requestScope.username}!
    </h1>
</body>
```

So, to come back to your question:
In your Servlet you can set the Parameter with

```
request.setParameter(<<PARAMETERNAME>>,<<VALUE>>)
```

In this Servlet you can call normal Java-Functions. First step for you is to read through tutorials :)